# How do I send a message to a channel in a specific Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I want a bot to await for a DM response, which would nab certain details from the response and paste it into a specific server. I can't figure out how to send the message to a channel in the specific server.

Comment: Can you show your code so far

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to send a message to a specific `Channel` on a specific `Guild` (server), you need to first know which `Guild` are we "talking about".

You can declare the `Guild` object in multiple ways, for example, if you have access to the `Guild`'s name, you can declare it by finding it on the bot's cached guilds (which include the servers the bot is in).

Let's say the DM you receive always includes the `Guild`'s name as its last "word" and the `Channel` name as its second to last one.

```js
client.on("message", function(message) {
    if(message.channel.type == "dm") {   // Checks if the message was received through DM and not through some other channel
        const words = message.content.split(' ');
        const guildName = words[word.length - 1]; // Declares guildName as being the last word from the message
        const channelName = words[word.length - 2]; // Equally, channelName is the second to last word
        
        const recipientGuild = client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.name == guildName);

        if(recipientGuild) {
            const recipientChannel = guildName.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === channelName);
            
            if(recipientChannel) recipientChannel.send(message.content);
            else console.log("There is no channel with that name in that guild!");
        }
        else console.log("There is no cached guild with that name!");
    }
});
```

Hopefully this will give you an idea on what you need to do.